# RoR audio_tag helper multiple source files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, audio

I have seen lots of javascript answers on how to achieve cross browser audio playback but would rather use the multiple src tag of HTML5

```
<audio>
    <source src="demo.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
    <source src="demo.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> 
    <!-- If no support at all. -->
    HTML5 audio not supported 
</audio>
```

I am using the rails helper tag but can't see how to define multiple sources

audio_tag("demo.ogg", :id => "soundDemo")

I tried audio_tag("demo.ogg", :src => "demo.mp3", :id => "soundDemo") but this didn't work.

Does anyone know the syntax that will work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a late late reply but I came across this issue today and this link should answer your question!

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4661#issuecomment-8407652

Basically it was not possible but will be included it a future stable release with the first parameter as an array of sources.